# How decode JSON file from Bundle using Codable

Tags: swift, codable

I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong when getting my JSON data in a state where I can start using it. I have a few idea, but not sure how to overcome them.

Here is a Country struct I am using to hold country data:

```
struct Country: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var country: String
    var capital: String
    var nationalLanguage: String
    var population: Int
}
```

Here is the code I am using to decode that data. This is in my viewDidLoad method and is building, but crashing and throwing my fatalError as soon as the app launches:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "countries", withExtension: "json")!
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let countryStruct = try decoder.decode(Country.self, from: jsonData)
            print(countryStruct.capital)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Unable to load data")
        }
    }
```

And here is a snippet of my JSON file which I dragged into my project's navigation:

```
[
    {
    “id”: 1,
    “country”: “United States”,
    “capital”: “Washington D.C.”,
    “nationalLanguage”: “English”,
    “population”: 328,239,523
},
{
    “id”: 2,
    “country”: “Canada”,
    “capital”: “Ottawa”,
    “nationalLanguage”: [“English”, “French”],
    “population”: 37,151,728
},
```

I also have a countryArray at the top of my main view controller that I THINK I need to use, but I'm really not sure.

```
var countryArray = [Country]()
```

Comment: `let countryArray = try decoder.decode([Country].self, from: jsonData)`. Your JSON is an array of `Country` objects, but you're trying to decode a single object. Also, don't hide errors with a generic error in `catch` - you would have seen a descriptive error message that would have led you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code you provided didn't fix my issue, but I'm sure it'll help after I fix my initial problem. I also updated my error message. I'm now receiving the error `No string key for value in object around character 10.`. Could it be some way that I created my json file? All I did was create a .txt file, typed out my content, saved and converted to a .json file type.

Comment: nationalLanguage for Canada is not a String.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not valid.

- As you mentioned the quotes are not valid
- Comma delimiters are not allowed in double nor float values

Also, your JSON is inconsistent since in the first object of the json array the `nationalLanguage` property is a simple `String`, but in the second is an array of `String`s.

So, your JSON should probably change to something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "country": "United States",
        "capital": "Washington D.C.",
        "nationalLanguage": ["English"],
        "population": 328239.523
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "country": "Canada",
        "capital": "Ottawa",
        "nationalLanguage": ["English", "French"],
        "population": 37151.728
    }
]
```

Your model will be changed to something like this:

```
struct Country: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var country: String
    var capital: String
    var nationalLanguage: [String]
    var population: Double
}
```

And the decoding will be:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "countries", withExtension: "json") {
    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let countryStruct = try decoder.decode([Country].self, from: jsonData)
        print(countryStruct.capital)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```